# X axis label being cut off in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

The label for my e letter is getting cut off. Do you know how I can fix this?

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)

p<-ggplot(data=english, aes(x=V1, y=V3))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue") +
  labs(x="Letter", y="Frequency") +
  geom_text(aes(label=V3), vjust=0.4, hjust=-0.1, size=3.5)
p + coord_flip()
```

Chart:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `ylim` option in the y axis (because you use `coord_flip` later) definition in ggplot, something like this

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(english[,"V3"]), max(english[,"V3"])+5)
```

Comment: I get Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale when using this.

Comment: how about `+ xlim(c(0,15))`

Comment: Hi, the problem was  scale_x, should have been scale_y. It works now. I'm curious if any point is greater than 15, but i set the limit to 15, what happens?

Comment: to avoid that just leave it automatic with `c(min(V3),max(V3)+5)`. I didn't see you used `coord_flip`, that's why it should be the y axis

Comment: Hi, i'm getting object 'V3' not found

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you. Unrelated quick question, do you know how to increase the space between each bar?

Comment: Exactly how to increase the space i don't know how, but you could change the `width = 0.1` in the `geom_bar`